# Help understanding smooth covector field on a real closed interval in standard coordinates

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, line-integrals

In page 138 in John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, he stated the following:

"We begin with the simplest case: an interval in the real line. Suppose $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a compact interval, and $\omega$ is a smooth covector field on $[a,b]$. If we let $t$ denote the standard coordinate on $\mathbb{R}$, $\omega$ can be written $\omega_t = f(t)dt$ for some smooth function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$."

I don't get why $\omega$ can be written $\omega_t = f(t)dt$. From what I understand, I have
$$ \omega: [a,b] \rightarrow T^{\ast}([a,b])$$ $$t \mapsto \omega_t: T_{t}([a,b]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ As $T^{\ast}([a,b]) \cong [a,b]$, we have $\omega_t:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I am not sure how to carry on from here.

Comment: $T^*([a,b]) \simeq [a,b]$ is not true

Comment: A hint: what is the tangent space to the manifold $M=[a,b]$? Use $t$ as a (global) coordinate on $M$. The space you are interested in is the dual of $TM$.

Comment: @Didier Oh sorry, I meant that $T_{t}([a,b]) \cong [a,b]$

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon The tangent space to $[a,b]$ is $[a,b]$ itself. From what I see, it seems like $dt$ in $f(t)dt$ comes from the fact that $\frac{d}{dt}$ spans $T_{t}([a,b])$ and so, the dual basis will be $dt$? But what about $f(t)$?

Comment: @shakebaba97 The tangent space to $[a,b]$ at a point $t\in [a,b]$ is $\Bbb R$, not $[a,b]$.

Comment: Consider this: we are considering the segment as a 1-dimensional manifold. The tangent space at any point then is a 1-dimensional vector space. The coordinate $t$ gives a generator for this space, $\partial_t$. A vector field assigns to each element of $[a,b]$ a multiple of $\partial_t$. What is a co-vector field?